# java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror : no Jsmile in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on the project with smile library and Jsmile.dll file. My project is working perfectly in eclipse with all functionalities but when I export the project as runnable .jar file it gives following error. I have linked Jsmile.dll to smile.jar sucessfully even after that it is showing an error when exported as runnable .jar file. How can I resolve the problem please guide me.
[Build Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9LKl.jpg)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh7xV.jpg)